# Location of databasefile in Visual Studio 2015 with Ripple Emulator

Tags: sqlite, visual-studio-2015, ripple

I'm looking for a way to locate the database of the ripple emulator. With Chrome normally this is in the default/databases/url/ folder. But I cannot locate this with the ripple emulator.

Does anyone have an idea where the ripple emulator stores it's data?

Answer (score 2):

Apparently you can open a new tab in the ripple chrome browser and put as url the following :

chrome://version/

In the info you get, you can find the user-data-dir.